# Text Input in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

**Goal**

I am trying to write a basic file which I can import in all other programs that will have a simple function that will take entry from the user and then return it.

**Code**

For that I have the following code:

```
class takeInput(object):

    def __init__(self,requestMessage,parent):

        self.string = ''
        self.frame = Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()        
        self.acceptInput(requestMessage)

    def acceptInput(self,requestMessage):

        r = self.frame

        k = Label(r,text=requestMessage)
        k.pack(side='left')
        self.e = Entry(r,text='Name')
        self.e.pack(side='left')
        self.e.focus_set()
        b = Button(r,text='okay',command=self.gettext)
        b.pack(side='right')

    def gettext(self):
        self.string = self.e.get()
        self.frame.destroy()
        print self.string

    def getString(self):
        return self.string

def getText(requestMessage,parent):
    global a
    a = takeInput(requestMessage,parent)
    return a.getString()
```

And I also added some script level code so as to test this:

```
root = Tk()

getText('enter your name',root)

var = a.getString()

print var

root.mainloop()
```

And what is really baffling me is that:

1. `var` does not have the value that I entered it has the empty string `''`
2. `a.string` variable has the value that I entered and I checked this from the shell.

**Also** When I tried to assign the string returned from `a.getString()` to `var` in the shell, then it worked.

**note** I am new to Tkinter programming and dont fully understand how the `mainloop()` works. So maybe this is were the problem is. But I am not sure.

**Specs**

OS:Linux Mint 14

Python IDLE 2.7

**Please** help me out with this issue.

Comment: Mainloop is nothing more than an infinite loop that looks roughly like `while the_main_window_exists(): get_the_next_event(); process_the_event()`. There's nothing particularly mysterious about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flow of your code goes like this:

- the main scope calls `getText`.
- `getText` creates a `takeInput` object `a`.
- the `takeInput` object initializes itself, creating Labels & buttons etc.
- `getText` returns `a.getString()`, which returns `self.string`, which still has its default value, the empty string.
- the main scope prints `var`, which is empty.

So far, all of this has taken place within the span of a few nanoseconds. The user hasn't even seen the window yet.

the main scope then calls `root.mainloop()`, which finally gives the user the opportunity to interact with the window. But it's too late. `var` has already been printed.

If you want `getText` to not return until the user has submitted his text, then `mainloop` has to occur inside `getText`, not after it.

```
from Tkinter import *

class takeInput(object):

    def __init__(self,requestMessage):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.string = ''
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack()        
        self.acceptInput(requestMessage)

    def acceptInput(self,requestMessage):
        r = self.frame

        k = Label(r,text=requestMessage)
        k.pack(side='left')
        self.e = Entry(r,text='Name')
        self.e.pack(side='left')
        self.e.focus_set()
        b = Button(r,text='okay',command=self.gettext)
        b.pack(side='right')

    def gettext(self):
        self.string = self.e.get()
        self.root.destroy()

    def getString(self):
        return self.string

    def waitForInput(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

def getText(requestMessage):
    msgBox = takeInput(requestMessage)
    #loop until the user makes a decision and the window is destroyed
    msgBox.waitForInput()
    return msgBox.getString()

var = getText('enter your name')
print "Var:", var
```

Comment: SIr: Will it be fine if I just print the value after I do `mainloop()`? Is that correct? I checked it and it does work.

Answer (score 12):

As other answers tell, you print `var` before entering the mainloop, that is, before your window is actually running, and your program is waiting for user input.

You could rely on `tkSimpleDialog` family to get your input:

```
import Tkinter
import tkSimpleDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
var = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Name prompt", "enter your name")
print var
```

If you want to pursue your way, you could perform your print from the "ok" button callback (`gettext` in your case). You could also generate a virtual event when "ok" is pressed and bind to this event in your main program (http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/virtual-events.html)

Comment: Yes. I found this to be the easiest way to do things!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your test routine already prints out the value of `var` before the dialog has been shown, let alone text being entered. (You can easily validate this by adding some `print` statements to your test code.) This is because the call to `mainloop()` is at the very end. Instead, you should call `mainloop` *after* creating the frame, but *before* reading and returning the input, e.g. it might go to your `getText` method:

```
def getText(requestMessage,parent):
    a = takeInput(requestMessage,parent)
    parent.mainloop()
    return a.getString()
```

This still does not work really well, as you have to close the dialog (click the `[x]`-button) even after clicking on 'okay', and I am not sure how to fix this.

However, note that there already *is* a module for this, `tkSimpleDialog`, providing methods such as `askstring(title, prompt)` that show just such an input dialog. So you might either use those, or look at the source code (found in `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk` or the like) to find out how it's done.

Comment: "you have to close the frame even after clicking on okay". This is because the callback for the "okay" button only destroys the frame. The root window is still undestroyed, so `mainloop` will continue looping. If you destroy the root in the callback instead of just destroying the frame, then `mainloop` will end.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, thought so, but I was not sure what this would do when creating this input dialog from within another Tk frame.

Comment: No sir. I don't intend to close the window as I have to  print some other things in the application that I am building.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog

root = tkinter.Tk()
# withdraw() will make the parent window disappear.
root.withdraw()
# shows a dialogue with a string input field
youtube_url = simpledialog.askstring('YouTube URL', 'Enter the youtube URL of the video', parent=root)

if str(youtube_url).startswith('http'):
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Comment: It would be better to explain, what your doing, so people can find it useful, even if its in the form of comments