# How to pass a variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
server = 'svr'
database = 'db'
username = 'sa'
password = 'password' 

   connection = pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)


if connection:
    print("Connection to [", database, "] was successful.\n")

cur = connection.cursor()

root = Tk()
root.title = "Scrap Report"
root.geometry = '400x400'

lb1 = Label(root, text='Enter JobNo')

lb1.pack()

txt1 = Text(root, height=2, width=10)
txt1.pack()
mainloop()

ESTIMATED LABOR COST
cur.execute(''' ... +JobNo+... ''')

data = cur.fetchall()
totLabor = 0
for row in data:
    totLabor += row[0]
print(totLabor, 'Labor Cost')
```

I am a huge python novice, and I have researched several different ways of doing this, and have been unsuccessful every time. I know the `tkinter` code is rough, I just keep uprooting it every time the variable pass is unsuccessful. I need to pass the `txt1` user entry to the variable `JobNo`, run the SQL query, and print the results. I am not sure if the `Text()` call is correct. The `JobNo` variable is a `str()`. I can provide more information if required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Input in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522336/text-input-in-tkinter)

Comment: contents = txt1.get("1.0", tk.END)    does not work?